# Function: 'find' not defined for std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

only like this find data,hvae big data in vector?

```
std::vector<uint32_t> rules;
for (auto iter = rules.begin(); iter != rules.end(); ++iter) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <algorithm>
std::vector<uint32_t> in
auto a = find(in.begin(),in.end(),15);
```